# react-router with components in their own files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I'm working on a web application using react and have some problems with react-router. According to the tutorials I read I can access the router in version 3.0.0 with `this.props.router` and programmatically change the location with `this.props.router.push('/home')` for example.

In all those tutorials unfortunately, all the components are in the same file. However, my structure is to have every component in its own file.
The router is defined in the `index.js` file.

```
/src
   /pages
      Home.js
      Landingpage.js
index.js
```

Above is the relevant part of my project structure. The following is the code of my `index.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Landingpage from './pages/Landingpage'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    IndexRoute,
    IndexLink,
    Link,
    browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import './index.css';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Landingpage}/>
            <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What I want is to access the above router instance in the files in my `/pages` directory. I tried several ways from the various tutorials, for example use `withRouter(componentName)` in the `index.js` file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both `Home` and `LandingPage` components have `location` and `router` props, if you want `Result` to have them too, use `withRouter`.

Comment: How can I access these props?
I have my components defined with `export default class ClassName extends React.Component {...}`.

Comment: @Bless Tried what you said, but I'm getting the following warning now and the page won't show:

_Warning: Unknown props `router`, `params`, `location`, `routes` on Landingpage tag. Remove these props from the element. 
    in Landingpage (created by withRouter(Component))
    in withRouter(Component) (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router (at index.js:17)_

I changed my class definition to `class ClassName extends React.Component {...} export default withRouter("ClassName").

Comment: @Bless Also imported withRouter from react-router in my Landingpage.js and Home.js.

Comment: @Bless Tried that, now I'm getting a setState(...) warning plus an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: @Bless Added a constructor `constructor() {
        super();
    }` to my Landingpage class after reading some answers here regarding the error I mentioned before.
The following function gets called and shows the alert:
`routerTest() {
        alert("routerTest :D");
        this.props.router.push('/home');
    }`

However, now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null` on the line after the alert.